# PyCharm can not autocomplete the code of dlib

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm, dlib

in python shell

import dlib

dlib.image_window

it can autocomplete the code

you can see the image here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw53N.png)

but in pycharm, there is nothing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH82c.png)

how to solve this problem in pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using sublime as the Python ide,and it is no problem like pycharm