# Why after i compile C++ code to install dlib and OpenCV,then my Intelicode Doesnt work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

As the title,after i using CMake to compiling OpenCV source code and dlib code to enable CUDA,they can work with CUDA in Python, but my Intellicode doesn't work

```py
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
 
In [1]: import dlib
 
In [2]: dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA
Out[2]: True
 
In [3]: import cv2
 
In [4]: cv2.cuda.printCudaDeviceInfo(0)
*** CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking) *** 
 
Device count: 1
 
Device 0: "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          11.70 / 11.70
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    7.5
  Total amount of global memory:                 6144 MBytes (6442123264 bytes)
  GPU Clock Speed:                               1.20 GHz
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(131072), 2D=(131072,65536), 3D=(16384,16384,16384)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(32768) x 2048, 2D=(32768,32768) x 2048
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     2147483647 x 65535 x 65535
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                No
  Device is using TCC driver mode:               No
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
      Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously)
 
deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version  = 11.70, CUDA Runtime Version = 11.70, NumDevs = 1
 
 
In [5]:
```

And that`s what happend in my Visual Studio Code

[image]

So, how should i do with that? There's only Github Copilot works lol...

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Comment: you should rather as authors of `Visual Studio Code` for this problem. I think they should have place for `Issues` on GitHub.

Comment: There's a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618168/pycharm-can-not-autocomplete-the-code-of-dlib) on pycharm.